# OpenVPN Access Server and Network Manager

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, client

I have installed OpenVPN Access Server on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server. On the client side I use Network Manager.

The VPN server is part of a private **10.42.24.0/24** network.

In the Admin GUI for the server I changed the default Dynamic Ip Address Network from 172.27.224.0/20 to **10.42.25.0/24** and then created a user.

I configured a new vpn client in Network Manager with the ovpn file. It works.

I am now wondering how to configure the routing on the client to only use the connection for the private network, not anything else. I know I need to tick "*Use this connection only for resources on its network*" and fill in Address, Netmask and Gateway in *IPv4->Routes* ... But I have no idea what values to add to include everything in the 10.42.24.0/24 network?

Also I would like to know if there is any other config values on the server that I should be aware of.

[EDIT]

Output from client while connected to VPN:

```
ip -4 route
default via 10.42.25.161 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0b1 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.42.25.160/28 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.42.25.162 metric 50 
123.456.789.128 via 192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0b1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.11 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev eno1 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown
```

Comment: Give me a bit to answer, I'm in the middle of work stuff too so don't have a ton of instant available time :)

Comment: Just grateful to get some guidance.... take your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Open Access Server - Web GUI

I discovered that what I want is called "**split tunneling**". For this to work it is especially important to have the correct value in #4 (that is the one I missed).

1. **Configuration -> VPN Settings -> Dynamic IP Address Network**

   - Value: 10.42.25.0/24
   - *Comment: The local network accessed through this VPN is 10.42.24.0/24. I reserved another local network for the VPN called 10.42.25.0/24.*
2. **Configuration -> VPN Settings -> Should client Internet traffic be routed through the VPN?**

   - Value: No
   - *Comment: The purpose of this VPN is solely to gain access to the local network.*
3. **Configuration -> VPN Settings -> Group Default IP Address Network (Optional)**

   - Value: [blank]
4. **Configuration -> VPN Settings -> Specify the private subnets to which all clients should be given access**

   - Value: 10.42.24.0/24
   - *Comment: This field is important. The GUI will fill it automatically, and you should check that it contains the right value.*
5. **User Management -> User Permissions**

   - *Comment: Add a user, and press "More settings" to set the password*
6. **Configuration -> Network Settings -> Admin Web Server.**

   - (Local ip): Yes
   - Listen on all interfaces: No
   - *Comment: Because I don't want the admin GUI publicly available.*

Everything else I left untouched at default values.

## Network Manager

In network manager, create a new VPN based on the opvn file, and then go to the ipv4 tab.

Below the **Routes** headline, Tick the "*Use this connection only for resources on its network*" option and fill in

**Address**: 10.42.24.0,

**Netmask**: 255.255.255.0

**Gateway**: 0.0.0.0